# How to remove a commit that shouldn't be a part of a branch due to branching too late after push?

Tags: git, rebase

I had a branch representing one set of changes that interacted with files XYZ. I decided to start working on another component of the project that interacted with files ABC (e.g. no mutually inclusive files). Mistakenly, I committed changes and then branched instead of stashing those changes so now work done to XYZ is accidentally included in the second branch. Unfortunately, I've already pushed the commits to remote version of this branch. I've tried to make a diagram below:

```
            /-G--H  # second branch
        /--E  # first branch
-A--B--C
```

What I meant to do is this:

```
        /--G--H # second branch
-A--B--C
        \--E # first branch
```

The second branch has already been pushed with  `git push -u origin second-branch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no problem to "move" the branch; checkout the second branch and rebase it, starting after E, onto commit C.

So from this situation:

```
* cb796d8 (HEAD -> second) H
* 0bc85b6 G
* d2c6ff8 (first) E
* ba28890 (master) C
* 41598db B
* 625c73b A
```

I just say

```
git rebase --onto master first second
```

and presto, I've got this:

```
* a305755 (HEAD -> second) H
* 18ebe9f G
| * d2c6ff8 (first) E
|/  
* ba28890 (master) C
* 41598db B
* 625c73b A
```

However, you will run into trouble when you try to push the result; you'll probably have to use force, because remotes don't like it when you attempt to change history, and if you are cooperating with others on these branches, you will have to warn them of what you're about to do.

Comment: Got it, thanks - I'm new to rebasing (and git in general), but my intuition was to checkout the second, go into the interactive rebase, and just drop commit E. Is this roughly correct?

Comment: Yeah, but now wait until you try to push it. :)

Comment: Thankfully, these two branches were independent work, so just forcing works fine in my case

Comment: That's what I was hoping!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to rebase:

```
git checkout second-branch
git rebase --onto C E
```

This will move all commits after E on top of C.

Now push your branch:

```
git push --force
```